# How close window that opened in a thread in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

By specification i build an application that monitors certain resource. Now i have a main window that when an event occurs throws an alert that specification must be a big window with bright colors. 
I gave solution to the problem as follows

```
 private void StatusChanges(Alarm m, EventArgs e)
        {

            //Compares two 32-bit signed integers for equality and, if they are equal, replaces one of the values.
                if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref running, 1, 0) == 0)
                {
                    newWindowThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
                                                                     {

                        try
                        {
                            // Create and show the Window
                            Alert tempWindow = new Alert();

                            tempWindow.Show();
                            //if (cancelRun)
                            //    tempWindow.Close();

                            // Start the Dispatcher Processing
                            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();



                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {

                            throw;
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            running = 0;

                        }

                    }));

                    // Set the apartment state
                    newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

                    // Make the thread a background thread
                    newWindowThread.IsBackground = true;

                    newWindowThread.Start();

                }


            }
            else
            {


                if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref running, 0, 1) == 1)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.FromThread(newWindowThread).InvokeShutdown();
                        Alert tempWindow = new Alert();
                        tempWindow.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {

                        //throw;
                        MessageBox.Show("Todo esta ok");
                    }

                }

                //running = 0;
            }
        }
```

This  method is executed from at interval by a Timer

my goal was when the alarm will end the process of removing the alert window, I used Thread.Abort (); did not work, and sometimes the program threw an exception and showed no visual studio in aplition happening outside, try using `threa.Join ();` but it didn't work, until

```
System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.FromThread use (newWindowThread) InvokeShutdown ().;
```

this at least stopped the showing up of the window, but when I create the

```
Alert tempWindow = new Alert();
```

in the initialize constructor

```
SoundPlayer player = new Sound ("../../Sounds/BOMB_SIREN-BOMB_SIREN-247265934.wav");
  player.PlayLooping();
```

and when I close the window

```
player.Stop();
```

Now if not but I do the next

```
 Alert tempWindow = new Alert();
                        tempWindow.Close();
```

the sound continues to play

I know that's not the best solution, but it works. 
I would like to give me your opinion, and give me suggestions on how to improve the code.

Comment: Don't create multiple UI threads.  You're putting yourself into a world of hurt by doing that.  Avoid the entire situation to begin with by *not* doing that.  Have just one UI thread that is responsible for manipulating your entire UI.

Comment: @Servy but How I show another window without the main window loses focus

Comment: If that's your question *then ask that question* rather than all of this.  That said, if all you want to do is find out how to set the focus to a given window, you should be able to find the answer to that question with some simple research.

Comment: @Servy Really my problem is that I have a window that runs my main code and want to show another window without the code of the main window stops running, even I want to execute actions in the second window without stop running the code in the main window

Comment: You should not be running *any* non-UI code in the UI thread.  You should be creating a new thread if you have non-UI CPU bound work to do, and do the work there, rather than creating a new UI thread to display a UI while you do long running CPU bound work in a second UI thread.  Use the UI thread for updating the UI, and non-UI threads for non-UI work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking a quick look at your code, what you're doing is closing the temp. window incorrectly. You are creating a brand new Window when you want to close the existing one.
This should be updated so that the existing temp Window is saved so that that the same instance can be closed later.

I've also updated the Closing of the temp Window so that it's thread shutdown's after it has closed.

I updated the code as follows:

```
Alert _tempWindow;

private void StatusChanges(Alarm m, EventArgs e)
{
    //Compares two 32-bit signed integers for equality and, if they are equal, replaces one of the values.
        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref running, 1, 0) == 0)
        {
            newWindowThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                try
                {   
                    // Create and show the Window
                    _tempWindow = new Alert();
                    _tempWindow.Close += OnTempClosed;
                    _tempWindow.Show();

                    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    running = 0;
                }

            }));

            // Set the apartment state
            newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            // Make the thread a background thread
            newWindowThread.IsBackground = true;
            newWindowThread.Start();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref running, 0, 1) == 1)
        {
            try
            {
                _tempWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)_tempWindow.Close);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //throw;
                MessageBox.Show("Todo esta ok");
            }
        }
        //running = 0;
    }
}

private void OnTempClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.FromThread(newWindowThread).InvokeShutdown();
}
```

Comment: A second UI thread shouldn't be used *at all*.  This is not the proper design for a program.

Comment: @Servy, then how can you run, let's say, an animated custom splash screen otherwise?

Comment: @MikeSpike The same way you do literally anything else.  You do the UI work in the one UI thread, and you do the non-UI work in non-UI threads.

Comment: @Servy there's a scenario where, after the background work, some UI initializations had to be done as well. Perhaps, there's a more elegant solution to this, but having 2 UI threads helped me do main window initialization while showing the animated splash screen(which is implemented as a separate window)

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to work with the UI just from the one thread. So rather than creating a whole new dispatcher, why not simply dispatch the new window logic to the existing UI thread (after all, doesn't the timer already end-up on the UI thread all by itself?).

Why are you starting the new window in a new thread? What are you hoping to accomplish by that?

Your close code doesn't make sense:

```
Dispatcher.FromThread(newWindowThread).InvokeShutdown();
Alert tempWindow = new Alert();
tempWindow.Close();
```

Let's walk through this. First, you shutdown the dispatcher of the second UI thread. This means that all the messages that would flow to the window - don't.

Then, you create a *new* window, on the original UI thread, and you close that. What's that supposed to accomplish? You want to close the window that you've opened before, not a new window!

In practice, you need to keep a reference to the original window you've opened - the reference to it's thread isn't really important. Now, if you really want to keep using your two-UI-threads approach, you'd do this instead:

```
alertWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(alertWindow.Close);
```

This will tell the message loop on the (already opened) alert window to close the window, as soon as it can.

With that out of the way, there's just too many things wrong with your code. For one, you're using way too low level operations (`Interlocked.CompareExchange` to maintain alert / no alert logic?). Two, your comments are completely useless - you're just saying what the next line does, literally - that's not helpful. Instead of

```
// Compares two 32-bit signed integers for equality and, 
// if they are equal, replaces one of the values.
```

You want to use something descriptive of what you're trying to achieve, not *how* you're doing it:

```
// If we're the first ones to attempt to change the running flag,
// we'll create a new alert window.
```

Note how that comment also quite nicely shows that you're doing something very weird.

Three, you're needlessly creating threads (and even more so, UI threads - there should really only be one except for very specific circumstances). There's no reason whatsoever to create the new window in a new thread. Why are you doing that?

Four, your exception handling isn't very helpful either. For one, you can omit the `catch` clause if all you're doing is rethrowing the exception anyway - you can just use `try ... finally` alone. More importantly, the exception is going to be propagated to that new thread, not your old one - this will most likely cause your application to crash completely.

Comment: If you have clarifying questions to ask of the question author you should be posting them as a comment on the question, not as an answer to the question.

Comment: @Luaan About of comment you're right, i put the comment of help of visual studio on the method as it caused doubt, you're right about try... finally, but i only put the code that caused me doubts.