# Problem to close WPF project using an external C# project

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

A little bit of context: I've got an external application (TestStand) which calls and communicates with an WPF (MVVM) app. Those interactions are made through another project which allows me to easily instantiate view and viewmodel thanks to static properties and methods of this interface project.

You will find a picture of a simple diagram of the architecture.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/IziKu.png)

My problem is the following:

I launch the view, through an STA apartment setted thread routine (in order to be able to access to the mainWindow constructor). As the view's datacontext is linked to an instance of the viewModel, I'm able to acess to the properties and methods of this viewModel (after that the binding magic does the job between view and viewmodel).
My problem occurs when I'm trying to close the view. In fact as the first thread opened the view, it becomes it's owner (the view is handled by the thread) and I'm not able to do it by myself.

Here is the Thread which is used to launch the view :

```cs
public static void IHMSiteGisement(SequenceContext context, string nameAssemblyParameters, out bool errorOccured, out int errorCode, out string errorMessage)
{
    errorOccured = false;
    errorCode = 0;
    errorMessage = string.Empty;
    viewModel = null;

    newWindowThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(OpenWindow))
    {
        Name = "WindowManager",
        IsBackground = true
    };
    newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    newWindowThread.Start();
}
```

And here is the OpenWindow methods called by the delegate 'ThreadStart' :

```cs
private static void OpenWindow()
{
    AppWPF = new MainWindow();
    viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
    AppWPF.DataContext = viewModel;
    AppWPF.Show();

    Dispatcher.Run();
}
```

First I simply tried to close the view by using `view.Close()`.
SPOILER ALERT that didn't work --> Visual Studio told me that I couldn't access this methods because the view is managed by a specific         thread and the one I'm using currently is not the same.

Then I'm trying to use the first thread to execute the view.Close() command. So I modified my 'OpenWindow' method to do it as following :

```cs
private static void OpenWindow()
{
    AppWPF = new MainWindow();
    viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
    AppWPF.DataContext = viewModel;
    AppWPF.Show();

    //Dispatcher.Run();

    while (!IsAskedtoClose);
        AppWPF.Close();
}
```

I commented the code line (Dispatcher.Run() because if not, the code never reached the while loop. The test was successful if you forget to mention that the while loop has freezed my GUI.

Next I tried to use my first thread and with another delegate method but I got the same error as the first try.

I also tried to use `Application.Current.Shutdown();` but the `Application.Current()` returns null value when the app is launched by TestStand, (not when I'm launching by app console).

I'm pretty sure that the errors I got are due to my misunderstanding of thread mechanisms, and what I'm looking for by posting here, is to have a technical answer in order to fix my problem, but also to have or to be able to find knowledge to understand threads and their mechanisms.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How close window that opened in a thread in wpf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23369231/how-close-window-that-opened-in-a-thread-in-wpf)

Comment: Where have you called `view.Close()` first?

Comment: @akseli I'm looking to the post, sound's good. I'm trying to adapt it to my problem. If yes I will post my new code

Comment: @Rekshino in a separated methods, I was pretty sure this solution was not ok due to thread management but we never know.

Comment: *how should I resolve this topic and display my solution?* Post an answer?

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution I implemented

First I open the application :

```
public static void OpenHMI(SequenceContext context, out bool errorOccured, out 
int errorCode, out string errorMessage)
    {
        errorOccured = false;
        errorCode = (int)EErrorCode.NoError;
        errorMessage = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            _newWindowThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WindowThreadRoutine));
            _newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            _newWindowThread.Name = "WindowManager";
            _newWindowThread.IsBackground = true;
            _newWindowThread.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errorOccured = false;
            errorCode = (int)EErrorCode.ErrorWhenTryingToOpenHMI;
            errorMessage = string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Here is the thread routine launched throught the open method :

```
private static void WindowManagerThreadRoutine()
    {
        try
        {
            _appWPF = new MainWindow();
            _viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();

            _appWPF.DataContext = _viewModel;
            _appWPF.CloseAppAsked += (sender, args) => { OnCloseCommand(); };
            _appWPF.Show();

            Dispatcher.Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

And then, here is how I close my app :

```
 public static void CloseHMI(SequenceContext context, out bool errorOccured, out int errorCode, out string errorMessage)
    {
        errorOccured = false;
        errorCode = (int)EErrorCode.NoError;
        errorMessage = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            if (!(_appWPF == null))
            {
                _appWPF.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)_appWPF.Close);
            }

            if (!(_newWindowThread == null))
            {
                Dispatcher.FromThread(_newWindowThread).InvokeShutdown();
            }

            if (_newWindowThread.IsAlive)
            {
                _newWindowThread = null;
                _appWPF = null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errorOccured = false;
            errorCode = (int)EErrorCode.ErrorWhenTryingToCloseHMI;
            errorMessage = string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Hope this will helps, thanks for the comment and support.
I'm open to any suggestions to improve my answer.